# typescript union type type inference?

Tags: typescript

```
type TestType = {
    value:string
    run:(v:string)=>void
  }
|
{
  value:string[],
  run:(v:string[])=>void
}
  
var obj:TestType = {
  value:'12',
  run:(val)=>{ // Why is val any? instead of string?
  }
}
```

I need value is string then val is string, value is string[] then val is string[]

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be to have a generic type that replaces the union with a constraint on generic argument

```
type TestType<T extends string|string[]> = 
{
    value: T
    run: (v: T) => void
}
  
var obj: TestType<string> = {
  value:'12',
  run:(v)=> { 
  }
}
```

**Edit:** the compiler can infer the type automatically, without the need to provide the generic type but an auxiliary function must be
used like:

```
type TestType<T extends string|string[]> = 
{
    value: T
    run: (v: T) => void
}

function wrap<T extends string|string[]>( obj: TestType<T>) {
  return obj;
}

var obj = wrap({
  value:'12' as string,
  run:(v)=> { 
  }
});

console.log( obj.value );
obj.run('foo');
```

In this example, the function is called **wrap**. It's generic but the compiler is smart enough to infer its signature based on the argument provided. Note however, that the `'12'` must be cast up to `string`, otherwise the `run`'s argument would be inferred as `12` rather than as `string`.

Comment: Thank you, is there any way to make TS intelligently know the type of val? I want to omit the step of manually specifying the type

Comment: @XiaoShang: edited my answer to provide additional information.

Answer (score 1):

Because TypeScript verifies that the function implementation you provide, of type `(v: any) => void` is compatible with the variable it's being assigned to, of type `(v: string) => void`, which is the case (that's why there is no error). But that doesn't change the inline function implementation's type. The `(v: string) => void` type only applies to the caller:

```
obj.run(2);  // KO
obj.run('test'); // OK
```

If you need the parameter to be typed as `string` inside the implementation, do it explicitly:

```
var obj: TestType = {
  value: '12',
  run: (val: string) => {
  }
}
```

And if you're only concerned about the compiler error, you can just disable the [`noImplicitAny`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitAny) option.

Comment: is there any way to make TS intelligently know the type of val?